# Seaborn - displot normalize KDEs for two different sample batches

Tags: python, seaborn, displot

I was wondering if there is a quick way to normalize the KDE curves (such that the integral of each curve is equal to one) for two displayed sample batches (see figure below).

So far I use:

```
sb.displot(data=proc, x="TPSA", hue="Data", kind="kde", legend=False)
```

Giving me the following plot:

[non-normalized KDE Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8qIm.png).

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the `hue` parameter is set, seaborn by default normalises with respect to the area of all kde curves combined. If you'd like to normalise each curve independently (so the area under each curve is 1), you should provide the displot/kdeplot with `common_norm=False`.

e.g. in your case

```
sb.displot(data=proc, x="TPSA", hue="Data", kind="kde", legend=False, 
           common_norm=False)
```

Comment: Hi @Tom B. I mean that each curve should have an integral of 1. If you have a look at my figure you will see that this is currently not the case.

Comment: Apologies - I think the issue is by default, when using ```hue```, seaborn uses the total area of all curves as the normalisation. If you set ```common_norm=False``` when creating the displot, does that fix the issue? If so I shall edit the answer!

Comment: that does the trick! Thank you very much!! I must have missed it in the documentation.

Comment: No problem! I have just edited the answer.  The parameter is not explicitly listed in the [displot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) documentation. You have to follow the link under the `kwargs` parameter to the [kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) documentation to find it.